# $P(X \le 2Y \le 3Z)= ?$

Tags: probability

Suppose X,Y,Z are iid expo($\lambda$)

$P(X \le 2Y \le 3Z)= ?$

i see that : $0\le X\le 2Y$;$\qquad \frac{X}{2}\le Y\le \ \frac{3}{2}Z \qquad \frac{2}{3}Y \le Z \le \infty$

But i cannot evaluate their limits for integration $\int \int \int dxdydz$.

I am not used to dealing with 3 random variables.Any other method which can be used in these kind of situations

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you´re on  the right track. We have just to ensure that

$$\frac{2}{3}Y \le Z < \infty , \ \frac{X}{2}\le Y< \infty \  \textrm{and} \ 0\leq X<\infty$$

The random variable $X$ must not be further constrained, since $Y$ is already constrained by $X$. Therefore the integral is

$$P(X\leq 2Y\leq 3Z)=\int_0^{\infty} \int_{0.5\cdot x}^{\infty} \int_{2/3\cdot y}^{\infty} e^{-z\cdot \lambda} e^{-y \cdot \lambda} e^{-x \cdot \lambda}  dz \, dy \, dx$$

For $\lambda=1$ we get $P(X\leq 2Y\leq 3Z)=\frac{18}{55}$

Comment: i guess it is 3Z instead of 3Y

Comment: That´s true. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because of independece:$$P(X\leq 2Y\leq 3Z)=\iint_DP\left(\frac12x\leq Y\leq \frac32z\right)e^{-\lambda(x+z)}\ dz \ dx$$
for some domain $D$.

And because of the distribution given

$$P\left(\frac12x\leq Y\leq \frac32z\right)=\begin{cases}e^{-\lambda\frac12x}-e^{-\lambda\frac32z}&\text{ if }\ \ 0\leq x\leq3z\\0&\text{ otherwise }. \end{cases}$$
Now we have an idea about $D$:

[image]

So, our integral to be evaluated is

$$\lambda^2\int_0^{\infty}\int_{\frac13x}^{\infty}\left[e^{\lambda\frac12z}-e^{-\lambda\frac32x}\right]e^{-\lambda(x+z)}\ dz \ dx.$$

Comment: Your [Integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E(infty)+int_(1%2F3*x)%5E(infty)+(e%5E(-3%2F2*z)-e%5E(-0.5*x)+)*+e%5E(-(x%2Bz))++dz++dx) is negative ($\lambda$ =1).

Comment: @callculus: why is the integral negative?

Comment: I don´t really know, but w.a. told me that: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E(infty)+int_(1%2F3*x)%5E(infty)+(e%5E(-3%2F2*z)-e%5E(-0.5*x)+)*+e%5E(-(x%2Bz))++dz++dx)

Comment: @callculus: I know now. Fix that immed.

Comment: @callculus: the sign is OK now. (I had to change the sign of the integrand.) However, our results are different now. ???

Comment: It seems that our results are different.